# Designing complex query builders in java/jpa/hibernate

Tags: java, design, sql, query, jpa

I need to build complex sql queries programatically, based on large filter conditions.

For example, below are few sample/hypothitical filter conditions, based on which i need to fetch users

Country: india

States: Andhra Pradesh(AP), Gujarat(GUJ), karnataka(KTK)

Districts: All districts in AP except 3 district, 5 any districts from GUJ, all district from KTK except 1 district

Cities: All cities in AP, all cities except few, include only 50 specific cities from KTK

Villages: similar conditions like above with varies combinations...

Currently, we have a query builder, which is very complex in nature, and not easy to modify/re-factory for improvements. So, thinking of complete re-design of it.

Any suggesations on how to build this kind of complex query builders programmatically using some best practices/deisgn patterns?

Comment: So... basically you're asking for an end-to-end solution from us? Or is there a specific question here that I'm missing?

Comment: Edited my question to make it short and clear..

Comment: try with torpedo query: http://torpedoquery.org/

Comment: torpedoquery api looks similar to hibernate criteria api, had a look at source code but I dont see anything on building very complex queries, or am I missing something..

Answer (score 2):

With torpedoquery your query could look like this

```
 public List<User> findUsers() {
    User from = from(User.class);
    City city = innerJoin(from.getCity());
    with(city.getCode()).in("one", "two").or(city.getCode()).notIn("three", "four");
    District district = innerJoin(city.getDistrict());
    with(district.getCode()).notIn("exclude1", "exclude2");
    State state = innerJoin(district.getState());
    with(state.getCode()).eq("AP").or(state.getCode()).eq("GUJ").or(state.getCode()).eq("KTK");
    with(state.getCountry().getCode()).eq("india");

    return select(from).list(manager);
}
```

I push on github the example if you want to take a look https://github.com/xjodoin/torpedoquery/tree/master/src/test/java/org/torpedoquery/jpa/examples

Answer (score 0):

I am sure your queries can be divided into "N" different kinds of queries;
E.G. some queries for geographical location, some for counts, etc.

If your database supports SELECTing from views, why don't you define one or
more views for each type of query, and then do a SELECT
from the view to filter by the parameter for that view?

You may also be able to rename columns in the view to standardized
search parameters passed in from the application: E.G.
in one case STATE could be PARAM1, CITY could be PARAM2, 
in another case, STATE could be PARAM1, ZIPCODE could be PARAM2.
Having views with the some of the same column names will save
your modules from having to be completely different.  (You
can have a lookup table that maps the views and parameters;
this will allow you to easily add new types of searches).

For example, SEARCH1 contains PARAM1 and PARAM2; PARAM1
is STATE, and PARAM2 is city, and the view name and parameters
for SEARCH1 are all stored in a lookup table.

This might make it easier for you to write your
application; you can have one module for each kind of view etc.